# Wide dashed lines in Postscript

Tags: postscript

The code below draws a wide dashed curve. The curve is so wide that the dashes overlap. The output seems wrong in some of the places the black dashes overlap. I've tested this in Preview on Mac OS X and Ghostscript. Can anyone explain?

```
%!
50 0 translate
500 dup scale
0.3 setlinewidth
[0.05 0.03] 0 setdash
0.1 0.1 moveto 0.2 2 0.6 -1.0 1 1 curveto
stroke
showpage
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to try `eofill` and/or `eoclip` to see if they help. By default postscript uses a "winding" rule to determine what/where to fill. Even/odd can also go wrong though, and I'm not sure it'll actually fix your program. It'll (almost) certainly change what gets filled, but the result may easily still be different from what you really want.

Comment: @Jerry, Exactly. If the default fill rule is nonzero winding, why do we see those white parts in the overlaps?

Comment: I probably should have written a bit more--it looks to me like the fill above is based on an even/odd rule, even though PS is supposed to use nonzero winding by default (e.g., based in part on the black quadrangle where two white parts overlap). Therefore, the first step would be to set things to ensure it's using nonzero winding instead of even/odd.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The way to do that is replace `stroke` with `strokepath fill`.

Comment: @luserdroog, that almost did it but I still get some strange geometry. Thanks.

Comment: Stroking is hard to get right. See the paper "Converting Stroked Primitives to Filled Primitives" to be presented at SIGGRAPH 2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me, Acrobat Distiller produces a PDF file where the dash segments don't show the eofill behaviour. The JAWS PostScript interpreter also doesn't exhibit this. Presumably Mac OS/X Preview uses Ghostscript to render PostScript files for previewing.